# If $x^2+bx+a=0$ and $x^2+ax+b=0$ have a common root $c$, Then what values of $(a,b)$ would work?

Tags: contest-math

Let $a$ and $b$ be distinct integers. If $x^2+bx+a=0$ and $x^2+ax+b=0$ have a common root $c$, Then which of the following statements are true?

1) $c*(a+c)=-b$

2) $a+b=-1$

3) $a+b+c=0$

4) $c=0$

**Update**

I just tried to sub $c$ into both of the equations:

$c^2+cb+a=0$ and $c^2+ac+b=0$ which then gives us the equality

$c^2+cb+a=c^2+ac+b$

$ => cb+a=ac+b$

$=> b(c-1)=a(c-1)$

which gives me then a=b which is contradictory because the integers are supposed to be distinct.

*Update #2*
Ok it looks like 1) is true, 2) is true, 3) is true, and 4) is false .. right?

Comment: Have you tried the simplest approach, for example substituting $\;c\;$ in both equations and seeing what happens??

Comment: That only works for multiple choice and I fail to see how that is good from a pedagogical point of view.

Comment: @ChrisK, whom are you addressing? My comment? Well, he *has* a multiple choice...

Comment: Yes, he **has** multiple choice, but how often does one really have that luxury: high school contests, SAT, GRE and that's pretty much it.

Comment: Chris K , what exactly is wrong with DonAntonio's approach ? The problem asks us to evaluate the validity of a given set of sentences . How else would one take on this problem , other than just plugging in c ?

Comment: @ChrisK, I refer to the question asked as *it is asked*. I cannot begin guessing or assuming stuff, like "how ofter this or that". In this site I try to help people *with his questions* as much as I can, not to give them whole (or even partial) university courses.

Comment: BTW, the question is either part of a much developed, complete question...or else it is a poorly worded and low-level one, as the correct option (1) is clear when one substitutes *only* in the second equation, and thus the first one is superfluous.

Comment: Okay... fine. I retract my comment. Yes, indeed, more than one answer is valid. So, it would make sense to check on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: As for (4) it is clearly false, since then $a = b = 0$, but we already known that $a$ and $b$ are distinct.

Answer (score 1):

We know that $c^2+bc+a = 0$ and $c^2+ac+b = 0$. Subtract to get $c(b-a)-(b-a) = 0$ or $(b-a)(c-1) = 0$. This means that either $b = a$ or $c = 1$. If $c = 1$, then $1+a+b = c+a+b = 0$.

Comment: $a = b$ is nonsensical since then the quadratics are the same.

Comment: Nothing in the statement says the quadratics are distinct.

Comment: If you look at the last comment from the OP, he clearly states that they are supposed to be distinct and besides, I think we can all agree that this is a terrible problem, even for contest standards.

Comment: The version of the question I saw was the first one, before the edit. With the edited version, Choice 3) becomes correct.

Answer (score 0):

Factor Theorem implies $x-c$ is a factor of $x^2+ax+b-(x^2+bx+a)$, and this is equal to $(a-b)(x-1)$, so $c=1$, let $r$ be the another root of $x^2+ax+b$ then $(x-1)(x-r)=x^2-(1+r)x+r=x^2+ax+b$, so $r=b$ and $a=-(1+r)=-1-b$. Therefore $a+b=-1$.

Answer (score 0):

Express $$x^2+bx+a=(x-c)(x-d)$$
$$x^2+ax+b=(x-c)(x-f)$$ 
Matching the coefficients of the powers of $x$ for both equations, we have
$$c+d=-b$$
$$c+f=-a$$
$$cd=a$$
$$cf=b$$
Solving for $d$ and $f$ in terms of $a$ and $b$ we have
$$d=a,f=b$$
leading to $c$ having only one possible value, which is $1$.

Thus we have $$c+a=-b\Rightarrow a+b+c=0$$
as well as
$$a+b+1=0\Rightarrow a+b = -1$$

Also, $$c(a+c)=a+1=-b$$

Thus, options (1), (2) and (3) are true.